# Bootstrap Modal in front of Angular Material Select Dropdown

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, angular-material

I am building an angular application and running into a weird bug. I have tried several things and looked for several answers.

I have a simple bootstrap modal and a angular material mat-select within a form.

Here is an image of what I'm talking about for reference.

[image: Here is the picture.]

Heres the code:

```
<form #dormForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="saveDorm(dormForm.value)">
  <div class="container">
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-select ngModel [value]="dormName" name="dormName" placeholder="Pick One!" required>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let dorm of dorms" [value]="dorm.value">{{dorm.viewValue}}</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
      <mat-error *ngIf="!dormForm.valid">
        Please select a valid choice
      </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
    <br>
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput placeholder="Instructions" ngModel name="instructions" id="instructions" type="textarea">
    </mat-form-field>
    <br>
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit" [disabled]="!dormForm.valid">Next</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Everything is appearing fine, but the dropdown list appears BEHIND the modal.

Some things I have tried:

```
.mat-select-menu-container, 
.mat-open-menu-container {
    z-index: 999999 !important;
}

.cdk-global-overlay-wrapper, .cdk-overlay-container {
    z-index: 99999 !important;
 }
```

Haven't found a working solution, going on 2 days now.

Comment: Updated the code.

Comment: Please consider using the Angular Material dialog component instead of mixing Bootstrap and Angular Material!

Comment: Also, it might be the cause of the bootstrap modal having a larger `z-index` than the select component.

Comment: How would I fix that?

Comment: i am stuck with the same error, mostly it's because if the z-index of the modal is larger than the z-index of the select drop down, and i don't want to go with material dialog, it very annoying, if you found the solution please let me know